# Detect if firefox is FirefoxPortable or not from addon scope

Tags: firefox-addon, portable-applications

I am trying to make my addon support portable Firefox, I got everything working, but I want to support portable and non-portable from same addon. I don't want to make a separate release for portable users.

So I'm trying to detect from my addon if the Firefox it is running in is portable. This has turned out to be very tricky.

These are other places where people are trying to help:

- http://portableapps.com/node/41436
- http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=2830109
- https://ask.mozilla.org/question/639/how-to-detect-if-firefox-is-firefox-portable/

Answer (score 2):

I would get the `XREExeF` path, walk one directory back and check if directories `AppInfo` and `DefaultData` exist there.

`Firefox` directory is there too, but it might be named different for Aurora and Nightly portables.

```js
var exeFile = FileUtils.getFile("XREExeF", []);
var defaultdata = exeFile.parent.parent;
var appinfo = defaultdata.clone();
defaultdata.append("DefaultData");
appinfo.append("AppInfo");

if(defaultdata.exists() && appinfo.exists() && defaultdata.isDirectory && appinfo.isDirectory())
  console.log("This is Portable Firefox");
else
  console.log("This is not Portable Firefox");
```

Comment: Thanks man for that idea I'll investigate and let you know what I come up with. :)

Comment: Test cases from users ::::::

* Non-port1: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`
* Non-port2: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`
* Non-port3: `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`
* Portable1: `C:\Users\C71ZQW1\Desktop\FirefoxPortable\App\firefox\firefox.exe`
* Portable2: `D:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox\Firefox\firefox.exe`

Comment: Thanks man I'll investigate that! (note to self: if exe.parent.parent is CurWorkD or descendent of than its portable)

Comment: thanks man for the detail edit. However   found exceptions, chineese users have this weird version of potrable and this wont work out for them always. especially if they install like direct on o a drive. I'm just going to createa a sepearte release ProfilistPortable so no need to detect if portable or not.